# Doctrine 2 DQL query with class name?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, dql

Is it possible in DQL, to specify the class name as a WHERE or GROUP BY clause?

That would be very useful when having a hierarchy of users, for example:

```sql
SELECT a FROM Article a
JOIN a.owner o
WHERE o.class = ?
```

```sql
SELECT u.class, COUNT(*)
FROM User u
GROUP BY u.class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the "INSTANCE OF" syntax in DQL:

your first example:

```
SELECT a FROM Article a
JOIN a.owner o
WHERE o INSTANCE OF 'Editor'
```

I'm not sure you do what you're trying to do in the second case, though.

Comment: `INSTANCE OF` is the closest solution to what I'm looking for (this includes subclasses as well, where I would have been interested to return instances of this class only). About the second case, this would be a query to return the number of objects for each class.